# How to show that $(3k+2,5k+3)=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I think I'm on the right track, but I can only figure out how to prove for a specific $k$ of my choosing... I don't know how to generalize it for all $k$:

> Assume $(3k+2,5k+3)=1$. Therefore, there exists some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(3k+2)x+(5k+3)y=1$.
>
> \begin{align}
> (3k+2)x+(5k+3)y&=3kx+2x+5ky+3y\\
> &=3kx+5ky+2x+3y\\
> &=k(3x+5y)+2x+3y=1
> \end{align}

If I let $k=0$, then $2x+3y=1$, and a particular solution is $(x_0,y_0)=(2,-3)$. But this same $(x,y)$ is not valid for other values of $k$... There does appear to exist upon inspection a solution for any value of $k$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is right and is invoking [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezouts_identity) which says that gcd$(a,b)$ is the smallest **positive** integer $c$ such that $ax+by=c$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore if we can show that there is a pair $(x,y)$ such that

$$(3k+2)x+(5k+3)y=1$$

Then we know that gcd$(3k+2,5k+3)=1$.  A quick check shows that $x=5, y = -3$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

$$
5 \cdot (3k+2) ~-~ 3 \cdot (5k+3) = 1 \qquad \forall k
$$

### Edit

I'm adding my comment to the answer: in order to remove the $k$s from the linear combination, (multiples of) 5 and 3 as coefficients are the only way. Since they do work, it's done!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$5(3k+2)-3(5k+3)=1$$

can you continue?

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the $5$ and $-3$ came from.

Comment: OK, I see how the math works out, but I don't see how you came up with those numbers. What procedure did you use?

Comment: we want x and y such that the k's get eliminated

Comment: In general, *Euclid's algorithm* can work, for finding the greatest common divisor.

Comment: @Berci I had considered that, but I couldn't figure out how to use it with the variables...

Comment: I assume he used the method of staring hard. An alternative would have been the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @agent154:- l.c.m.$(3,5)=15$ , so we have to get $15$ somehow , and we note that $15/3=5 , 15/5=3$

Comment: After trying again, I did figure out how to use the Euclidean algorithm with this question, and it gave me an answer of 1 as desired. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Of course. It's just multiplying through...

Answer (score 3):

Another, slightly different, proof goes like this: $\gcd(5k+3,3k+2)$ must divide both the sum and difference of the two, *i.e.*

$$\gcd(5k+3,3k+2) \mid \gcd(8k+5,2k+1).$$

But $8k+5=4(2k+1)+1$, so the gcd must also divide $1$, proving $\gcd(5k+3,3k+2)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Euclidean algorithm:
\begin{align*}
5k+3&=1\times (3k+2)+(2k+1)\\
3k+2&=1\times (2k+1)+(k+1)\\
2k+1&=1\times (k+1)+k\\
k+1&=1\times k+1\\
k&= 1\times k+0
\end{align*}
Therefore, the GCD of $3k+2$ and $5k+3$ is $1$. Additionally, there exists some $x$ and $y$ such that $(3k+2)x+(5k+3)y=1$. A particular solution is $(x,y)=(5,-3)$.